# Tableau How to color a chart based on two fields, one continuous and other discreet

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, hierarchy, level-of-detail

I have a data set from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/unanimad/us-election-2020?select=president_county_candidate.csv) and here is what it looks like:
[image]
Now I want to plot a map using Tableau which illustrates the advantage/disadvantage of Republican/Democrat. Just picture this, because I have already had the total votes of each party in every single county, it is easy to compare which party won a county. My idea is depicting this fact: if a county is won by Republican, then it should be in red; if by Democrat, it would be in blue; otherwise it would be white if being won by minor parties (I am not sure whether there was such a case).

Note that if the more overwhelming a party is within a county, the darker should the color be. For example, if a Republican won a county tinily by 0.1%, it should be light red; if a county is won by Democrat with a landslide, say 30%, then it should be deep blue.

My problem now is that with the given data, I have no ideas about how to demonstrate the gap of votes between different parties. I guess I might need to create a calculated field that shows the vote difference with a county. But is it the right solution?

---- EDIT----
I found an example: https://public.tableau.com/profile/clillich.kltv#!/vizhome/ElectionResults_5/Dashboard1, it looks good to me. It is just uncertain what its data source looks like.

Comment: @AnilGoyal Please provide any solution! Thanks!

Comment: Please see the solution proposed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you have shown is perhaps not related to chart as you want.  It shows only one measure.  Please proceed like this.

**Step-1** Create a calculated field `win margin in percent` with the following calculation

```
IF [Won] = TRUE then ([Total Votes] -
{FIXED [State],[County] : MAX(
IF [Won] = FALSE then [Total Votes] END )})/
{FIXED [State],[County] : SUM([Total Votes])}
END
```

**Step-2** Convert it to dimension (*by right clicking it*).

**Step-3** simultaneously create a group on party field as desired.

**Step-4** select both fields in dimension pane and create a new hierarchy (party-group first and win margin second).  Drag this heirarchy to marks card.  Convert both to colors.  The following gif may help

[image]

I think this serves your purpose.  Good luck

Comment: It looks very good to me already! Thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask: is it possible to change the color gradient? I saw your result is ranging from blue to orange, but it will be better if it is from blue to red.

Comment: Since the field has to converted into a discreet dimension, the color scales are editable manually.  However, there should be a workaround.  Let me try!

Comment: for two color scales there's an useful method to try.  Read [this](http://drawingwithnumbers.artisart.org/two-sequential-color-palettes-on-the-same-map/) and try.

Comment: If instead of fully continuous field you can divide the win_margin field in discreet intervals, the management/customisation of color will become too much easier.

Comment: I tried both continuous and discreet types, neither of them works for me.

Comment: Would grouping of win margin in intervals like 0-10%, 10-20%, etc. serve the purpose? I mean one shade for one interval

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but how can I select multiple elements when creating group? It is too demanding if I click every option one by one and add them to a group.

Comment: A calculation may be written for that. Still for changing the color allocated by Tableau the categories have to be selected and changed manually. By the way, the link I have posted earlier gives a beautiful method if only two color gradients are required.  Even a third one can be managed there.  I'll try to write that as an answer here, if you want it?

Comment: Absolutely! All tableau newcomers will thank you!